# Azure Cosmos Db with Mongo API

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

We have a social network app, and we are using Azure Cosmos DB with Mongo API

I have a Comments collection that has all users' comments with the creation date and i am doing an Aggregate with group on created date with date_trunc, to get the documents count like daily, weekly or monthly. also, with match on created date

Here is the scheme

```
{
   _id
   createdDate
   text
   userId
   postId  
}
```

Partition key is the **createdDate** .

Indexes:

- **_id** by default indexed (single field)
- **createdDate** (single field)

The problem is that when I do the aggregate on 58,000 documents it costs about 2845.2 RUs, just for one query and i think this is a lot.

The query is:

```
db.comments.aggregate([
 { $match : {createdDate: { $gt: 1672616989000, $lt: 1680824989000 }}}
 { $group : { _id : {$month:'createdDate'}, count: { sum : 1 } }}
 { $project : { _id:0, period: '$_id', count: '$count' } }
 { $sort : { 'period':1 } }
])
```

Results:

```
{"count" : 4862, "period" : 1}
{"count" : 53392, "period" : 2}
{"count" : 161, "period" : 3}
{"count" : 1, "period" : 4}
```

So, is there any way to reduce this huge number of RUs? Or is there any different way to do it?

Comment: Not enough info to know for sure but my guess is that date_trunc is causing the query to do a full scan rather than using the index. On way you might fix this would be to persist the date_trunc values when the comment is written to the collection then use a straight equality match in your query. I would also change the partition key from date to the largest time bucket for your queries to minimize the number of shards your queries traverse. For instance use monthly, then for that query as well as weekly or daily, you pass in that monthly value so other two queries are always in the same shard.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you're actually doing. Difficult to know what costs you 1700 RU without 1) some sample data and 2) the query you're running. Oh, and 3) the indexes you set up, and 4) the partition key you chose.

Comment: @DavidMakogon i just updated the question with the more details, and updated numbers, please let me know if you need more info

Comment: You also can't do ranges on partition keys (i.e. $gt $lt). If you want to understand your queries, read this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/troubleshoot-query-performance

Comment: @MarkBrown is there another way to do the logic that i am doing in a better and different way?

Comment: Yes. this sort of thing can be accomplished using MaterializedViews pattern and change streams, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/materialized-view. You could probably do all this in a single document, but design is up to you.